# Use Swashbuckle generated JSON file in Web API

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I have a JSON file which is generated by Swashbuckle for one of my Web APIs - Web API 1.

Now, I want to consume that JSON file[generated by Web API 1] in another web API 
->web API 2. So, that I can expose the methods from Web API 1 in Web API 2.

Is this possible?. How can I achieve this?
Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Comment: So you want the endpoints that are in Web API 1 to show up in the Swagger document for Web API 2, correct?  Do you also want those endpoints called as if they were part of Web API 2, or do you just want the documentation?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Yes, I would like for the endpoints to be called as if they were a part of Web API 2.

Answer (score 0):

So with the above information, I think that you have a couple of options:

First, you can duplicate the endpoints in Web API 2, and call the associated endpoint in Web API 1.  That obviously is not a very elegant solution, but it could be fairly simple to implement.

Second, you can add a reference in the Web API 2 project to point to the assemblies in the Web API 1 project.  I've done this in the past when converting an old, poorly written project to newer code.  Swashbuckle with see the controllers in the referenced assemblies, but you way need to play with some of the Swashbuckle settings.  You might also need to move any configuration information from Web API 1 into Web API2.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hmm...thats not something I am leaning towards..have actually ruled out the above two options and wanted to know if there is a way to use the jSon file to achieve the same...

Comment: The Swagger html file can be entirely replaced, and there is nothing to prevent you from retrieving the Swagger file for Web API 1 inside the HTML file and manually merging it with the one from Web API 2.  Could be easy or hard depending upon your javascript skills.  But the endpoints would probably be messed up